# How to change fragment in viewpager from another activity?

Tags: android

Case:
I have a viewpager with 3 fragments (in a MainActivity), fragment #3 has a button that open an activity Act.

Act has a button, when pressed I want to close Act and call viewPager.setCurrentItem(1) in MainActivity.

How can I do this? I tried to override the #3's onResume() method and call main.doSomething(), and it works, but onResume() is called every time I open #3!

thanks

Comment: Fragments can communicate back to their parent Activity with callback interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Best You code the button in fragment #3 to use startActivityForResult() rather than just starting an intent.

In the Button in Fragment 3 Do this

```
public static final int ACTRESULT = 1;
Intent i = new Intent(this,ActActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTRESULT );
```

In the Button in the Act Activity

```
//Do whatever you want to do
//and close Activity Act like this
mIntent = getIntent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent );
finish();
```

Back In the Button in Fragment #3, the following method is needed therefore added

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TWEET_SELECT:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           //Here you can do what you want when the Activity Act has been closed and 
           //the application returns to fragment #3
                         }
            }
}
```